# Django constance variable check in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to enable custom logging toggle check inside settings.py as shown below(the code is at the bottom of the file):

```
from constance import config


if config.CUSTOM_LOGGING:
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'formatters': {
            'standard': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] : %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'default': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': 'pd_temp/celery_logs/allume_feed_jobs.log',
                'maxBytes': 1024 * 100,  # 100 kB
                'backupCount': 5,
                'formatter': 'standard',
            },
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'handlers': ['default'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True
            },
        }
    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Any workaround for the above scenario would be very helpful. Thanks!
Ref: Django constance (https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Well you can not import models/apps/... in the settings.py file, since the load order is first the settings, and then loading the file. It might be better to subclass the handler, and there check if the configuration holds. But anyway, why not define a `CUSTOM_LOGGING` in the settings file itself?

Comment: I had an explicit CUSTOM_LOGGING in settings but wanted to give toggle option to the admin user to change it via django admin page, for seamless usage.

Comment: Well settings are normally (more or less) static elements. So in that case, it might be better to move the "toggle logic" into the handler class itself.

Comment: Thanks Willem, will try that method .